# Nginx: Is post_action skipped when Rails returns a X-Accel-Redirect header is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx, x-accel-redirect

The `post_action` in the config for my Nginx 1.4.2 instance is not firing (or does not appear to be). I'm wondering if it is because Rails is returning a `X-Accel-Redirect` header.  The ultimate goal is track when downloads hosted on S3 have completed.

**Step 1:** The request hits nginx at http://host/download/...

```
location ~ /download/ {
  proxy_pass http://rails-app-upstream;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  post_action @finished;
}
```

**Step 2:** After authenticating the request for the download file and marking the start of the download in the database, Rails returns the request with the following headers:

```
{ 
   'X-Accel-Redirect' => '/s3-zip/my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/0001.jpg`
   'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=download.jpg",
   'X-Download-Log-Id' => log.id.to_s,
   'X-Download-Mem-Id' => log.membership_id.to_s
}
```

**Step 3:** Nginx catches the `x-accel-redirect` header and hits this location that is defined:

```
location ~ "^/s3-zip/(?<s3_bucket>.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-.]*.s3.amazonaws.com)/(?<path>.*)$" {
  # examples:
  #   s3_bucket = my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
  #   path = downloads/0001.mpg
  #   args = X-Amz-Credentials=...&X-Amz-Date=...
  internal;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/s3_assets-access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/s3_assets-error.log warn;

  resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s; # Google DNS
  resolver_timeout 10s;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Host $s3_bucket;
  proxy_set_header Authorization '';

  # remove amazon headers
  proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";

  # no file buffering
  proxy_buffering off;

  # bubble errors up
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/$path?$args;
}
```

**Missed Step:** The following location called by the `post_action` in Step 1 is never fired. Is this because of the `x-accel-redirect` header, or because Step 3 uses a `proxy_pass`, or something else? This last location calls the rails route again once nginx has completed the request to mark the download as completed.

```
location @finished {
  internal;

  rewrite ^ /download/finish/$sent_http_x_download_log_id?bytes=$body_bytes_sent;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach to mix both techniques Nginx S3 proxy with X-Accel-Redirect. Each individual solves the same problem: offload backend and let Nginx handle download therefore backend is ready for new requests. What's the specific requirement to mix both together? Btw authentication can be done via [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html).

Comment: There's not requirement to mix the two. This was just my first attempt to solve this problem. I suppose I could just remove `internal` and add the `post_action` to the `/s3-zip/...` location, then have rails do a `redirect_to` for `/s3-zip/...`.  And I'm on 1.4.2, so no `auth_request` unfortunately.